# Running a same test case on multiple pages using selenium/protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I have written few test cases using selenium/protractor and running on single page. I need to run same test cases against multiple pages parallely / one by one. How to implement this type of scenario?

Comment: Multiple pages parallel.. Do you mean running single test against different URL or running same test in multiple browsers?

Comment: Thanks for considering the question, Its running a single test against different URLs

Answer (score 0):

if I got you right, use it.
in protractor.conf add this piece of code

```
multiCapabilities: [
  {'browserName': 'internet explorer'},
  {'browserName': 'chrome'}
],

maxSessions: 1,
```

browserName - which browser you want to utilize
maxSessions - how many of them
you can run in parallel at a time in the remote system.

Comment: Thanks Alexander! But my question is to run single test on multiple pages not on multiple browsers.

Comment: For example, I have simple test case to find broken links on page, where I need to run this same test case against multiple page at a time/ or running a command for one time.

Comment: this functionality doesn't exist as I know in any kind of UI tests. One of the options you can use it's running browser.get(your page) after all links on the previous page were checked

Answer (score 0):

Use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider

You can define different pages as data and run the same test one after another.